# Deleting a post after deleting a user associated with the post in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have implemented an admin model in rails that would allow me to have a list of users, and as the admin, I am able to delete the users. Some users wrote posts-- my issue is when I (the admin) delete a user that wrote a post and then destroy the post, I get an error that states: "undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
 nil:NilClass."

```
<% @reviews.each do |review| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= review.user.name%></td>
    <td><%= review.location %></td>
    <td><%= review.program %></td>
    <td><%= review.semester %></td>
    <td><%= review.review %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', review %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_review_path(review) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', review, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Add the whole error message and the code involved in the issue.

Comment: So added <td><%= review.user.name%></td> but when I remove it there isn't an error anymore, but my table won't show the user name

Comment: Add the controller you're using to remove the data, maybe you're trying to access to the same user after deleting it.

Comment: This is the review_controller.rb

  def destroy
    @review.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to reviews_url, notice: 'Review was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

Comment: I was able to figure it out! Thanks though

Comment: Maybe you could add your solution as an answer for the community to benefit from it!

Answer (score 0):

Associate the post with user with dependent destroy.
i.e.

**User Model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
end
```

**Post Model**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user 
end
```

The posts will be deleted automatically.